# Difference between os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) and os.path.dirname(__file__)

Tags: python, django, os.path

`settings.py` file of a Django project contains these two lines:

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

I want to know the difference as I think both are pointing to the same directory. Also it would be great help if you could provide some links os.path functions.

Comment: Did you try them both and compare?

Comment: No, they are not pointing at the same directory.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`BASE_DIR` is pointing to the *parent* directory of `PROJECT_ROOT`. You can re-write the two definitions as:

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT)
```

because the [`os.path.dirname()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) simply removes the last segment of a path.

In the above, the `__file__` name points to the filename of the current module, see the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__file__):

> `__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded, if it was loaded from a file.

However, it can be a *relative* path, so the [`os.path.abspath()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) is used to turn that into an absolute path before removing just the filename and storing the full path to the directory the module lives in in `PROJECT_ROOT`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you started your project using the `django-admin startproject my_new_app` command, then it creates a hierarchy as follows.

```
my_new_app
|
└───my_new_app
│   │   
│   │   settings.py
│   │   ...
|   manage.py
```

Then, `os.path.abspath(__file__)` returns the absolute path to the `settings.py` file, `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` returns the path to the inner `my_new_app` folder and `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` returns the path to the outer `my_new_app` folder.

In more recent versions of Django (e.g. version 4.2.5), instead of `os`, `pathlib` module is used, so an equivalent construct is:

```py
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
PROJECT_ROOT = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
```

---

There's a special case where if `settings.py` is already in the root directory on your environment (e.g. the C drive on a local machine) so that its path looks like `C:\settings.py`, then `BASE_DIR == PROJECT_ROOT` may be True. This is probably not how it should be, so if BASE_DIR and PROJECT_ROOT are the same, then you probably need to re-structure your project.